# asp gridview binding is very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using asp.net to display the result set from a back end.  For each record, I am displaying a checkbox inside a grid.  My requirement is to keep unchecked records on the front end.  Checked records will be processed, and will be removed. Along with this I am using paging and sorting techniques.

The issue is that when the checked records are processed, the grid needs to be bound again.  This binding is taking almost 40 minute.  (My resultset is 3.5 million records.)  Is this feasible or can this be changed?  How can I overcome the 40 minute delay?

Comment: Don't bring all 3.5M records at once from the backend! Use server-side paging and bring to grid only records needed for current page to display

Comment: There's surely no user who's going to go through 3.5 million records to find the one/s they need; they will require some sort of filter. Provide this before you search, and you can incorporate the criteria into your search to reduce the number of rows brought back in the first place.

Comment: `my resultset is 3.5 million records.)` answers your own question either change the query of how you are returning / retrieving the records or use some sort of paging I would love to see what kind of Query you are writing as well as what type of DBMS are you working against denormalized tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time a postback happens( on paging, sorting, button click etc...), your datasource will retrieve all of the 3.5 million records. This is true even though your gridview only show an x amount of records per page.

You either have to filter the query results to a manageable amount of records with an external control, like a textbox with a date.

Or [implement custom paging/sorting](http://www.google.com/search?q=gridview%20custom%20paging&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS503US503&oq=gridview%20custom%20pa&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8342j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl#q=gridview%20custom%20paging%20sorting).

[Linq is really good with this.](http://www.google.com/search?q=gridview%20custom%20paging%20linq&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS503US503&oq=gridview%20custom%20paging%20sorting%20lin&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.9070j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl)